# Simple Postgres SQL query not working for null values (when using IN condition)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres v11+ and want to return a dataset if col1 equals value1, value2, or null.

```
select * from table1 where col1 in (value1, value2, null);
```

Only thing is that the rows with null are not coming. I have also tried the reverse:

```
select * from table1 where col1 not in (value3, value4);
```

However, still the null rows are not coming. I know you can do this with a separate OR statement, i.e.

```
select * from table1 where col1 in (value1, value2) or col1 isnull;
```

But this doesn't work for me as I have additional conditions that get (incorrectly) passed when I use OR. (Basically I'd prefer to do this in a single shot).

What's wrong with postgres to where an in statement doesn't work with null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` fails pretty much all comparisons.  But it is particularly nefarious with `NOT IN`:  If any element in the `NOT IN` list is `NULL`, then the `NOT IN` never evaluates to "true".  It evaluates to either "false" or `NULL`.

Instead of these:

```
where col1 in (value1, value2, null);
where col1 not in (value1, value2, null);
```

You can use:

```
where (col1 in (value1, value2) or col1 is null);
where col1 not in (value1, value2) ;
```

`null` values will fail the second condition anyway.